# Perform Mongodb Aggregation in JMeter

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter, aggregate, mongodb-java

I'm trying to run a simple aggregation in JMeter using the the mongo-java-driver 3.8.  I'm new to JMeter and using Mongo with Java.  I used this tutorial as a starting point:

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter/

I modified the code from the Querying Documents section for use in the JSR223 Sampler as follows:

```
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates;

try {
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = vars.getObject("collection");

    Document result = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.sample(1)));

    vars.put("exampleDocumentId", result.get("_id").toString());

    return "Document with id=" + result.get("_id") + " found";
}
catch (Exception e) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
}
```

I get the following error in response for the Sampler result in the View Results tree:

```
Response code: 500
Response message: Exception: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException:
Cannot cast object 'com.mongodb.client.internal.AggregateIterableImpl@3c7a0022' with class
'com.mongodb.client.internal.AggregateIterableImpl' to class 'org.bson.Document'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collection.aggregate() function call returns [AggregateIterable](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/AggregateIterable.html) which cannot be cast to the document directly, you can use [Groovy head() method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#head(java.lang.Iterable)) which returns the first value from the Iterable instance like:

```
Document result = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.sample(1))).head()
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Based on the documentation head and first seem to be interchangeable. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#first(java.lang.Iterable). Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

1. As chuckskull said read the documentation:
   https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/driver/tutorials/aggregation/
2. You don't need blocks and don't use *forEach(printBlock);* at the end of your aggregate statement; instead use *first()* just as the tutorial mentioned above used on find statements.
3. If you're a novice (like me) just use the restaurant data suggested in the documentation when your getting a hang for how this works.

Here's a working example:

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Accumulators;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Projections;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Filters;

import org.bson.Document;

try {

    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create();
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("restaurants");

    Document result = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.sample(1))).first()

    vars.put("exampleDocumentId", result.get("_id").toString());

    return "Document with id=" + result.get("_id") + " found";
}
catch (Exception e) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention to the part of the error where it says: **Cannot cast object**.

The method [`MongoCollection#aggregate`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.11/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#aggregate(com.mongodb.client.ClientSession,java.util.List)) returns [`AggregateIterable`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.11/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/AggregateIterable.html). 
Changing `Document` to `AggregateIterable<Document>` will solve this problem.

Comment: I replaced:     Document result = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.sample(1))); with:  AggregateIterable<Document> result = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.sample(1))); and I now get the error: Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script38.groovy: 10: unable to resolve class AggregateIterable 
 @ line 10, column 30.
    AggregateIterable<Document> result = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.sample(1)));
                                ^

Comment: Are you adding imports?
`import com.mongodb.client.AggregateIterable;`

Comment: I now have:import com.mongodb.client.AggregateIterable; and
import com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates; The new error is: Response message: Exception: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.mongodb.client.internal.AggregateIterableImpl.get() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [_id]
Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), grep(), grep(java.lang.Object), getAt(int), wait(), any()

Comment: Please read the documentation!
https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/driver/tutorials/aggregation/

https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.11/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/AggregateIterable.html